# Html insert the 6 boxes for mac address value

Tags: html, macos

is possible create a wizard text box? created 6 boxes of 2 pairs.

00 : 11 : 22 : 33 : 44 : 55
or alternatively automatically insert ":" after each pair

mycode

```
<input style="height: 29px;" maxlength="17" name="os0" type="text" placeholder="00:aa:bb:cc:dd:11" />
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible.  Either 6 input boxes with some script that moves the cursor, or some kind of js formatting.

Comment: JavaScript can insert ":" if `length%3==2`. If you want separate boxes, you can have it automatically shift across if the box is full. Is this what you mean by a "wizard" text box, one that is automatic?